# Can sys.modules[__name__] throw an error even if __name__ is defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, sys

Is it possible for `__name__` to be defined -- we could write the following in a script somewhere:

```
x = __name__
```

... and yet, the line below would throw an error?

```
module  = sys.modules[__name__]
```

Comment: easily, if you don't `import sys` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Unless you tampered with `__name__` or `sys.modules`, no error should be raised as `__name__` should always be in `sys.modules`.

Unless you forgot to import `sys`.

```
# No import

sys.modules[__name__] # raise NameError
```

If you are having a `KeyError`, you might have overshadowed `__name__`.

```
import sys

__name__ = 'foo'

sys.modules[__name__] # raise KeyError
```

Or, less likely, you might have overwritten `sys.modules`.

```
import sys

sys.module = {}

sys.module[__name__] # raise KeyError
```